# Where AWS code build dump the source code and can we change its default location?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Actually we have a magento setup and its look for its source code in `/var/www/html` directory but code build dumps our code from github in default generated location which creates problems.

Comment: I would suggest that you reword your title and question (including more detail) to make it easier for other users to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

CodeBuild clones your GitHub repo to a non-deterministic workspace path. You should use the environment variable "CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR" as your workspace directory where the source is checked out. You cannot change this location.

More details about environment variables in  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html.